# Joining table to shapefile using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-joins

Joining shapefiles is a relatively straightforward proess in QGIS using 'add vector join' in the layer properties menu. I can add a csv file as a vector layer, as well as a shapefile, and join the two using a common field.

I would like to do a similar join using PyQGIS. However, I can't seem to find any documentation on how to go about this.

Is this possible to do programmatically using PyQGIS with 'add vector join' or the older 'Join by Attributes'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find working code for attribute joins in the source of processing JoinAttributes.py: https://github.com/rldhont/Quantum-GIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/JoinAttributes.py ... basically, you loop over both layers and compare manually.

Comment: The URL you provided is not available anymore...