# Joining table field with shapefile using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, shapefile, csv, attribute-joins

The following is currently unsuccessful at fulfilling a table field join to a point shapefile in QGIS.

All instances of the join object will print the proper values, and no error is flagged when processing - but the target layer does not exhibit any effect.

Something missing?

```py
Heads = QgsVectorLayer(headCSV, 'Heads', 'ogr')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(Heads)
self.iface.legendInterface().setLayerVisible(Heads,False)
grid = ftools_utils.getMapLayerByName(unicode('Grid'))
joinObject = QgsVectorJoinInfo()
joinObject.targetFieldName = str('ID')
joinObject.joinLayerID = Heads.id()
joinObject.joinFieldName = str('cellID')
grid.addJoin(joinObject)
grid.reload()
```

The following returns `'None'`. I expect this is actually supposed to return the field names to be joined  (e.g. - a clue to the mistake).

```py
print joinObject.joinFieldNamesSubset()
```

---

Added the following, and now the previous update command returns the accurate fields to be joined - yet the destination layer does not show 'joined' fields...

```py
joinObject.setJoinFieldNamesSubset(['someFieldName'])
```

Comment: Have you read [Joining table to shapefile with pyQGIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58387/joining-table-to-shapefile-with-pyqgis?rq=1) already?

Comment: indeed, this as well http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67062/pyqgis-joining-a-dbf-to-a-shapefile

Comment: sould be noted that join works on layer added in the registry. Otherwise no update fields would happen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has worked for me:

```
# Get input (csv) and target (Shapefile) layers
shp=iface.activeLayer()
csv=iface.mapCanvas().layers()[0]

# Set properties for the join
shpField='code'
csvField='codigo'
joinObject = QgsVectorJoinInfo()
joinObject.joinLayerId = csv.id()
joinObject.joinFieldName = csvField
joinObject.targetFieldName = shpField
shp.addJoin(joinObject)
```

The error you are facing is, believe it or not, by a typo in `joinLayerId`. The question is, why QGIS doesn't throw an error there?

Comment: You are exactly right.  Works beautifully now.  Highly appreciate the help. A mistake easily overlooked it seems without a syntax error. Thanks!

Comment: @gcarrillo "The question is, why QGIS doesn't throw an error there?" because your are creating a new python variable. Did you check if addJoin return false?

Comment: @LuigiPirelli addJoin returns True, giving no clue about any error or typo.

Comment: There's also an excellent [tutorial](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins_pyqgis.html) using this method.

Comment: Keep in mind that: the class [`QgsVectorJoinInfo`](https://qgis.org/api/2.18/structQgsVectorJoinInfo.html) has been renamed to [`QgsVectorLayerJoinInfo`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayerJoinInfo.html).

Answer (score 5):

If it's ok for you to use Processing algorithms for that, it's as simple as this (from the QGIS Python console):

```
import processing
res = processing.runalg("qgis:joinattributestable","/path/to/shape.shp","/path/to/table.csv","fieldShp","fieldTable","/path/to/output.shp")
layer = QgsVectorLayer(res['OUTPUT_LAYER'], "joined layer", "ogr")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

You can have a look at the [algorithm source code](https://github.com/rldhont/Quantum-GIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/JoinAttributes.py) so that you decide whether you want to adapt it for your own script.

Comment: While this is a great alternative, the need is a 'virtual join', as accomplished from the properties menu of a layer.  This is because the operation might be done repeatedly, and avoidance of data overhead is a must.

Comment: Well, you could still use temporary layers setting the last parameter of the algorithm to `None`, but I see your point.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent example, I was very useful, combine a shp with a csv file, here my example performed:

---

```
import processing
res = processing.runalg("qgis:joinattributestable","d:/areas_geoestadisticas_estatales.shp","d:/poblacion.csv","cve_ent","cve_ent","d:/union_shp_csv.shp")
layer = QgsVectorLayer(res['OUTPUT_LAYER'], "Capa Unida", "ogr")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

---