# copy column into another layer column programatically

Tags: pyqgis

I have two layers where different columns exist. I want to copy a layer column into antoher layer column programatically. I have done the below code so far:

```
layerNameValueSet = "PLATFORM"
#columnNameSet where to value add
columnNameSet = "ZONEID"

#LayerName Where to copy column values
layerNameValueGet= "LOT" 
#Above layer's[layerNameValueGet] cloumn name from value will be get for copy in layerNameValueSet
columnNameGet = "ZONEID"

#Getting layer of specifc name
layerNameValueSetObj = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(layerNameValueSet)[0];
layerNameValueGetObj = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(layerNameValueGet)[0];

fieldIndexToSet = layerNameValueSetObj.fieldNameIndex(columnNameSet)
fieldIndexToGet = layerNameValueGetObj.fieldNameIndex(columnNameGet)

for getFeature in layerNameValueGetObj.getFeatures():

    #this logic is not correct /taking too much time hanging

for setFeature in layerNameValueSetObj.getFeatures():
    if(getFeature.id() == setFeature.id()):
        layerNameValueSetObj.startEditing()
        updateValue = getFeature[columnNameGet]
        layerNameValueSetObj.changeAttributeValue(setFeature.id(), fieldIndexToSet, updateValue)
        layerNameValueSetObj.commitChanges()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally [**zip**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) help me to do this Job. I run [both loop simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39761495/how-to-run-two-loop-simeltanously-in-one-loop-in-python) in one loop and here is the answer:

```
import itertools
#layerNameValueSet Where to copy column values
layerNameValueSet = "PLATFORM"
#columnNameSet where to value add
columnNameSet = "ZONEID"

#LayerName Where to copy column values
layerNameValueGet= "LOT" 
#Above layer's[layerNameValueGet] cloumn name from value will be get for copy in layerNameValueSet
columnNameGet = "ZONEID"

#Getting layer of specifc name
layerNameValueSetObj = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(layerNameValueSet)[0];
layerNameValueGetObj = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(layerNameValueGet)[0];

fieldIndexToSet = layerNameValueSetObj.fieldNameIndex(columnNameSet)
fieldIndexToGet = layerNameValueGetObj.fieldNameIndex(columnNameGet)

#running two loops simeltenously so that copy one value into antoher
for getFeature, setFeature in zip(layerNameValueGetObj.getFeatures(), layerNameValueSetObj.getFeatures()):
    layerNameValueSetObj.startEditing()
    updateValue = getFeature[columnNameGet]
    layerNameValueSetObj.changeAttributeValue(setFeature.id(), fieldIndexToSet, updateValue)
    layerNameValueSetObj.commitChanges()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could : 
 - instead of editing / commiting in a loop. Build a list or even a dic. And so you would just need to commit once.
 - Why not use the join by attribut tool instead of reinventing the wheel: see [helpfull script](https://github.com/rldhont/Quantum-GIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/JoinAttributes.py)

this could also help : [link1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102119/how-to-change-the-value-of-an-attribute-using-qgsfeature-in-pyqgis), [link2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133573/join-table-field-with-shapefile-programatically-via-pyqgis)

Comment: actually my code is not working correctly i simply want to copy it from one column into antoher all data line by line.