# How much area is overlap

Tags: pyqgis

I am able to check if two geometries are intersecting through:

```
 if a.geometry().intersects(b.geometry()):
```

Is there any method available that tell me if how much one geometry is overlapping with other. Like 10% 50% 90% etc

Comment: How about the difference method?

Comment: where it is? is this built in i didnt find in geometry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate area for all the features using a loop:

```
for f in layer.getFeatures()
```

Getting the area can be done with :

```
f.geometry().area()
```

F being the feature 
Then simply do a.area()/b.area()*100

Comment: Thanks juls, i am checking it. is there not any build in function available

Comment: This won't give the geographical overlap area just the percentage of one regions area compared to another.

Comment: Thank for the logic. can u help me here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212223/copy-column-into-another-layer-column-programatically

Comment: it is perfectly valid but i got another problem i have one layer of polygon while other is line. now how can i compare? one consist of area while other consist of length

Answer (score 1):

From inspection of this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168266/pyqgis-a-geometry-intersectsb-geometry-wouldnt-find-any-intersections) it looks like you can do something like:

```
if a.geometry().intersects(f.geometry()):
        intersection = a.geometry().intersection(f.geometry())
        print intersection.area()
```

When you intersect two polygons this can return either a polygon, a line or a point (depending on how the two polygons intersect), if you intersect a polygon and a line it will return either the line that is within the polygon or a point if the line just touches the polygon. So you need to add some logic that decides whether to calculate the area of the overlap or the length of the line depending on what sort of geometry intersection has returned.

Comment: is there any way available to check that how much line contains inside polygon. actually I want to check that

Comment: use length instead of area to find the length of the line

Comment: i did but i have polygon which provide area while line provide length both are different things. how can i compare it

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212297/compare-how-much-line-contains-inside-polygon

Answer (score 0):

Divide the overlapped area by the whole area to get the percentage of overlapping:

```
intersection = a.geometry().intersection(b.geometry())  
totalArea = a.geometry().area() + b.geometry().area()  
percetnage = (intersection/totalArea)*100
```

Comment: is there any way available to check that how much line contains inside polygon. actually I want to check that

Comment: what do you mean by line ? is it another layer ?

Comment: A polygon layer geomoery contains a line which is another layer. i want to check that how much that line contains in polygon.

Comment: You can use **Spatial query** in QGIS to query lines intersecting with polygon and you will get all lines

Comment: actually i have to update attribute table column value on this comparison basis

Comment: You can create spatial join between the 2 layers and then update the column.  for more details check http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_joins.html