# Computing length of network inside rectangle in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, network

I have a QgsRectangle and a network layer of lines. How is it possible to calculate the length (or percentage) of the network that lies inside the rectangle?

I found this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212297/how-to-compute-the-share-of-a-line-that-is-inside-a-polygon-programatically?rq=1) that helps computing the percentage of a line inside a polygon, but I would love to avoid having to convert each rectangle in a polygon (I have almost 50000 rectangles) and iterating over that and over the whole line network (which is also some 25000 features).

Here is what I have:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import itertools

registry = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()
network = registry.mapLayersByName('network')[0]

#all of this is to create the rectangles that I'll need to compute later

ext = network.extent()

x1 = ext.xMinimum()
x2 = ext.xMaximum()
y1 = ext.yMinimum()
y2 = ext.yMaximum()

X, Y = range(x1,x2,100), range(y1,y2,100)
XY = itertools.product(X,Y)

rectDic = {}
for x,y in XY:
    p1 = QgsPoint(x,y)
    p2 = QgsPoint(x + 1000, y + 1000)
    r = QgsRectangle(p1,p2)
    rectDic[(x,y)] = r

#and this is where I get stuck

networkPerRect = {}
for pt in rectDic:
    r = recdic[pt]
    lenOfNetwork = length of network inside r #NEED HELP HERE
    networkPerRect[pt] = lenOfNetwork
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it's very difficult "to avoid having to convert each rectangle in a polygon ... and iterating over that and over the whole line network" because this is a geoprocessing problem. To understand which is the purpose of your code, I modified it by using a greater factor for each XY (10000) and p2 (100000) variables to reduce compute time and print the length of a network inside each generated rectangle. Code is:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import itertools

registry = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()
network = registry.mapLayersByName('line')[0]
feats_network = [ feat for feat in network.getFeatures() ]

#all of this is to create the rectangles that I'll need to compute later

ext = network.extent()

x1 = ext.xMinimum()
x2 = ext.xMaximum()
y1 = ext.yMinimum()
y2 = ext.yMaximum()

X, Y = range(int(x1),int(x2),10000), range(int(y1),int(y2),10000)
XY = itertools.product(X,Y)

rectDic = {}
for x,y in XY:
    p1 = QgsPoint(x,y)
    p2 = QgsPoint(x + 100000, y + 100000)
    r = QgsRectangle(p1,p2)
    rectDic[(x,y)] = r

#and this is where I get stuck

#networkPerRect = {}
for i, pt in enumerate(rectDic):
    r = rectDic[pt].asWktPolygon()
    r_geom = QgsGeometry.fromWkt(r)

    lenOfNetwork = 0

    for j, feat in enumerate(feats_network):
        if feat.geometry().intersects(r_geom):
            print "rectangle {:d} intercets feature network {:d}".format(i,j)
            lenOfNetwork += feat.geometry().intersection(r_geom).length()

    print "total length", lenOfNetwork

#    lenOfNetwork = length of network inside r #NEED HELP HERE
#    networkPerRect[pt] = lenOfNetwork
#
```

I used next arbitrary shapefile as network layer; previously converted in multipart to additionally improve compute time.

[image]

After running the code at the Python Console of QGIS, I got 96 total lengths:

```
rectangle 0 intercets feature network 0
total length 62350.5059025
rectangle 1 intercets feature network 0
total length 88243.6468944
rectangle 2 intercets feature network 0
total length 136207.054982
rectangle 3 intercets feature network 0
total length 13782.1451098
rectangle 4 intercets feature network 0
total length 63420.2492418
rectangle 5 intercets feature network 0
total length 73010.35539
rectangle 6 intercets feature network 0
total length 11730.7783419
rectangle 7 intercets feature network 0
total length 273051.100382
rectangle 8 intercets feature network 0
total length 48209.4105307
rectangle 9 intercets feature network 0
total length 27869.0695912
rectangle 10 intercets feature network 0
total length 199036.229632
rectangle 11 intercets feature network 0
total length 2387.5570924
rectangle 12 intercets feature network 0
total length 119356.014314
rectangle 13 intercets feature network 0
total length 46886.2287155
rectangle 14 intercets feature network 0
total length 130805.109208
rectangle 15 intercets feature network 0
total length 236789.965812
total length 0
rectangle 17 intercets feature network 0
total length 156467.459214
rectangle 18 intercets feature network 0
total length 88243.6468944
rectangle 19 intercets feature network 0
total length 61032.6921494
rectangle 20 intercets feature network 0
total length 207372.499041
rectangle 21 intercets feature network 0
total length 125942.428638
rectangle 22 intercets feature network 0
total length 46212.2146533
rectangle 23 intercets feature network 0
total length 36535.2901658
rectangle 24 intercets feature network 0
total length 26522.9013592
rectangle 25 intercets feature network 0
total length 53831.7003364
rectangle 26 intercets feature network 0
total length 63420.2492418
rectangle 27 intercets feature network 0
total length 133112.135442
rectangle 28 intercets feature network 0
total length 142873.607026
rectangle 29 intercets feature network 0
total length 227979.730828
rectangle 30 intercets feature network 0
total length 76088.1421981
rectangle 31 intercets feature network 0
total length 52184.7306027
rectangle 32 intercets feature network 0
total length 95085.4988114
rectangle 33 intercets feature network 0
total length 166856.172206
rectangle 34 intercets feature network 0
total length 88243.6468944
rectangle 35 intercets feature network 0
total length 200041.062615
rectangle 36 intercets feature network 0
total length 198722.874336
rectangle 37 intercets feature network 0
total length 75539.660579
rectangle 38 intercets feature network 0
total length 197639.165497
rectangle 39 intercets feature network 0
total length 175367.94436
rectangle 40 intercets feature network 0
total length 63420.2492418
rectangle 41 intercets feature network 0
total length 295511.810162
rectangle 42 intercets feature network 0
total length 143759.204944
rectangle 43 intercets feature network 0
total length 23794.5339165
rectangle 44 intercets feature network 0
total length 43819.3115298
rectangle 45 intercets feature network 0
total length 63420.2492418
rectangle 46 intercets feature network 0
total length 316886.314413
rectangle 47 intercets feature network 0
total length 115062.507231
rectangle 48 intercets feature network 0
total length 166651.755055
rectangle 49 intercets feature network 0
total length 144842.913784
rectangle 50 intercets feature network 0
total length 237873.674652
rectangle 51 intercets feature network 0
total length 153296.825078
rectangle 52 intercets feature network 0
total length 74998.9210491
rectangle 53 intercets feature network 0
total length 286855.530294
rectangle 54 intercets feature network 0
total length 240455.65256
rectangle 55 intercets feature network 0
total length 241573.583016
total length 0
rectangle 57 intercets feature network 0
total length 78796.8389007
rectangle 58 intercets feature network 0
total length 230526.469985
rectangle 59 intercets feature network 0
total length 39263.6576086
rectangle 60 intercets feature network 0
total length 121506.005452
rectangle 61 intercets feature network 0
total length 32071.1192815
rectangle 62 intercets feature network 0
total length 99443.0721743
rectangle 63 intercets feature network 0
total length 120635.800868
rectangle 64 intercets feature network 0
total length 167382.996967
rectangle 65 intercets feature network 0
total length 148984.427218
rectangle 66 intercets feature network 0
total length 257894.718748
rectangle 67 intercets feature network 0
total length 205379.337318
rectangle 68 intercets feature network 0
total length 38209.4105307
rectangle 69 intercets feature network 0
total length 259753.38373
rectangle 70 intercets feature network 0
total length 22071.1192815
rectangle 71 intercets feature network 0
total length 238378.879479
rectangle 72 intercets feature network 0
total length 15128.3133418
rectangle 73 intercets feature network 0
total length 97280.8708923
rectangle 74 intercets feature network 0
total length 181861.744605
rectangle 75 intercets feature network 0
total length 179822.38919
rectangle 76 intercets feature network 0
total length 96883.1892213
rectangle 77 intercets feature network 0
total length 46886.2287155
rectangle 78 intercets feature network 0
total length 46547.6789725
rectangle 79 intercets feature network 0
total length 177965.919194
rectangle 80 intercets feature network 0
total length 142710.94429
rectangle 81 intercets feature network 0
total length 33806.9227231
rectangle 82 intercets feature network 0
total length 330184.031065
rectangle 83 intercets feature network 0
total length 113718.046323
rectangle 84 intercets feature network 0
total length 190834.955395
rectangle 85 intercets feature network 0
total length 66572.4565858
rectangle 86 intercets feature network 0
total length 166228.537003
rectangle 87 intercets feature network 0
total length 159786.601184
rectangle 88 intercets feature network 0
total length 315027.649431
rectangle 89 intercets feature network 0
total length 74998.9210491
rectangle 90 intercets feature network 0
total length 82244.9255883
rectangle 91 intercets feature network 0
total length 270078.151876
rectangle 92 intercets feature network 0
total length 56560.0677791
rectangle 93 intercets feature network 0
total length 51817.6266959
rectangle 94 intercets feature network 0
total length 174284.23552
rectangle 95 intercets feature network 0
total length 218973.189506
```

To corroborate good code performance, I took last generated rectangle (visualized with QuickWKT plugin; as it can be seen at next image) and manually determined (with measure line tool of QGIS) length lines inside it.

[image]

Result was as expected.