# Adding point geometry to 311 datatset without compromising duplicates using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I'm not sure how best to phrase this problem so bear with me.

I'm analyzing 311 complaints about unshoveled sidewalks in Boston during 2016. Unfortunately the latitude and longitude data in the 311 data set provided by the city was unreliable. Fortunately for me, it DID include the addresses of each property reported for a violation. I downloaded the city's parcel shape files and cleaned up the 311 data set so that I can match each complaint to a particular property in the city. Each 311 complaint has a unique ID and some information I've coded regarding the nature of the complaint, whether a citation was issued, etc.

Here's my problem - some properties were reported more than once in 2016. Some were reported as many as five or six times over the course of the year. How can I add the geometry (and other attributes, preferably) from the parcel shapefiles to the 311 CSV? I produced a centroid points layer for the parcel data to make this simpler, but I'm stumped as to how I can include the parcel info in the 311 file while preserving the frequency of reports per address.

Comment: I'd say use a database... you're going to have much more success storing data that relates based on an ID than trying to manage this as 'only 1 record can have this geometry'... this is a classic issue we overcame by switching to PostGIS for our data.

Comment: Similar situation posted here: [Color in QGIS based on record of events in CSV file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224593/color-in-qgis-based-on-record-of-events-in-csv-file) I would suggest [`Virtual layer` solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/224689/84455) by @underdark.