# Joining layers with PyQGIS 3

Tags: attribute-joins, pyqgis-3

I am trying to join layers programmatically following the answers in the [Joining table field with shapefile using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133573/joining-table-field-with-shapefile-using-pyqgis)

```py
# Get input (csv) and target (Shapefile) layers
shp = iface.activeLayer()
csv = iface.mapCanvas().layers()[0]

# Set properties for the join
shpField = 'code'
csvField = 'codigo'
joinObject = QgsVectorJoinInfo()

...
```

But I get an error about [`QgsVectorJoinInfo`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayerJoinInfo.html) not being defined. I tried to import it with:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsVectorJoinInfo
```

(because the documentation linked above says that `QgsVectorJoinInfo` is in the `core` library).

How should I import it properly or otherwise make the above code work? (In general, how to tell from the documentation which library to import?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The class has been renamed from [`QgsVectorJoinInfo`](https://qgis.org/api/2.18/structQgsVectorJoinInfo.html) to [**`QgsVectorLayerJoinInfo`**](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayerJoinInfo.html).

You now need to call each join function with their associated parameter:

```py
...
csvField = 'id'
shpField = 'ID'
joinObject = QgsVectorLayerJoinInfo()
joinObject.setJoinFieldName(csvField)
joinObject.setTargetFieldName(shpField)
joinObject.setJoinLayerId(csv.id())
joinObject.setUsingMemoryCache(True)
joinObject.setJoinLayer(csv)
shp.addJoin(joinObject)
```

Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: @user3142418 - Glad you found it helpful :)