# Removing table join using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, vector, attribute-joins, remove

I joined a table to a layer in QGIS using code from this thread: [Joining layers with PyQGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/267784/193501).
Now I would like to remove the join. How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`QgsVectorLayer` possesses a method for that: [`removeJoin(joinLayerId: str)`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a6d9ac590b0d11dbe795c0891c8508542).

So, if `layer2` was initially joined to `layer1`, the code for removing the join may look like this:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject

layer1 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("LAYER 1")[0]
layer2 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("LAYER 2")[0]

ids_of_joins_in_layer1 = [join.joinLayerId() for join in layer1.vectorJoins()]

if layer2.id() in ids_of_joins_in_layer1:
    layer1.removeJoin(layer2.id())
```