# Is it possible to join the same table twice in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, attribute-joins

Basically, I have the layers above:

[image]

As shown in the image, I'm trying to join the layer `lines` with the layer `points` two times in a row so the labels of `origin_id` and `extremity_id` appear in the attribute table of the layer `lines`.

I tried with Joins in QGIS but unfortunately, I can only join the layer `points` once.

Is there a solution, please?

*Here is an example:*

[image]

*And here is the expected output:*

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to join twice? Does not seem to make sense to me. What is your final goal you want to achieve? Joining once, you can add **all attributes** from one layer to the other, no neet to repete this for each attribute separately.

Comment: In the layer `Lines` there is only ids of origin and extremity. I need to get their labels from another layer that is `Points`. That's why I need to join twice..

Comment: can you provide sample data?

Comment: Of course, I'll do that. One sec please!

Comment: Not clear what you join: you write about layers `lines` and `points`, but your screenshot shows a layer `cables`.. is this the same with the `lines` layer?

Comment: Duplicating the layer `points` is no option?

Comment: I think there is a design mistake if you think you have to join a table twice, maybe you want to rethink your problem. It's only a guess for the moment...

Comment: I added an example to my question. I think that @Babel's solution (duplicating `Points`) will allow me to make appear two fields `origin_label` and `extrem_label` in the layer `Lines`.

Comment: I added the expected output as well. The goal is make a new field that concatenate the two labels. It's a very basic problem but looks like I failed to describe it very well. By the way, duplicating the layer `Points` worked for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want to do is **not** joining layers, but creating two new attributes. You can achieve this with field calculator using this expression on the lines layer:

```
attribute (
    get_feature(
        'Points',  -- name of the points layer
        'id',  -- name of the attribute on the points layer
        extreme_id -- name of the attribute on the lines layer
    ),
    'label' -- name of the attribute on the points layer
)
```

[image]

Comment: I added a second clause for the origins as well and it worked. Thank you so much Babel ;)

Answer (score 3):

Beside duplicating the point layer or fetching the desired attributes in the Field Calculator, you can also achieve this goal using a ["Virtual layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers)

Using this approach, you can also compute your new field.

Go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` and enter the following query. Adjust the layer and field names.

Remember that virtual layers are computed in memory, so feel free to export it to another format if needed.

```sql
SELECT l.*, 
      pt1.label as label_origin, pt2.label as label_extreme, 
      pt1.label || ' To ' || pt2.label
FROM myLineLayer l
JOIN myPointLayer pt1
 ON l.origin_id = pt1.id
JOIN myPointLayer pt2
 ON l.extreme_id = pt2.id;
```

Comment: Thanks to you JGH, I learned this new trick ;)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is based on PyQGIS. It utilizes the [`QgsVectorLayerJoinInfo()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayerJoinInfo.html) class for joining purposes.

Proceed with `Plugins > Python Console > Show Editor` and paste the script below:

```py
# imports
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsVectorLayerJoinInfo

# original layer
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("union")[0]
field = 'id'

# target layer to join
target_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("points")[0]
target_layer_id = target_layer.id()
# params for the first join
target_field1 = 'from'
prefix1 = 'from_'
# params for the second join
target_field2 = 'to'
prefix2 = 'to_'

# First object to join
joinObject1 = QgsVectorLayerJoinInfo()
joinObject1.setJoinFieldName(field)
joinObject1.setTargetFieldName(target_field1)
joinObject1.setJoinLayerId(target_layer_id)
joinObject1.setJoinFieldNamesSubset(["date"])
joinObject1.setPrefix(prefix1)
joinObject1.setUsingMemoryCache(True)
joinObject1.setJoinLayer(target_layer)
layer.addJoin(joinObject1)

# Second object to join
joinObject2 = QgsVectorLayerJoinInfo()
joinObject2.setJoinFieldName(field)
joinObject2.setTargetFieldName(target_field2)
joinObject2.setJoinLayerId(target_layer_id)
joinObject2.setJoinFieldNamesSubset(["date"])
joinObject2.setPrefix(prefix2)
joinObject2.setUsingMemoryCache(True)
joinObject2.setJoinLayer(target_layer)
layer.addJoin(joinObject2)
```

*Input:*

[image: input]

Press `Run script` [image: run script] and get the *output* that will look like this:

[image: output]

---

**References:**

- [Joining layers with PyQGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267732/joining-layers-with-pyqgis-3)
- [Joining table field with shapefile using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133573/joining-table-field-with-shapefile-using-pyqgis)
- [Removing table join using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/418505/removing-table-join-using-pyqgis)
- [PyQGIS Developer Cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/index.html)