# Joining multiple layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, attribute-joins, batch, virtual-layer

I have about 25 GeoPackage files, each containing a table with an `"ID"` field and another with density information about that area. I want to join all those density information into one layer, using the `"ID"` as the linking criteria.

The problem is that "Join multiple attributes by field value" or the "Joins"-section in the layer properties can only join one layer at a time, so it would take a lot of time to process all of my files.

Is there another option to join all layers at once?

Comment: I tried, but this creates an output file for each join operation in this batch. I would like to get a single output file that combines all the tables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [Virtual layer](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` for that.

Use this query:

```sql
select
    *
from
    layer1 as l1,
    layer2 as l2,
    layer3 as l3,
    layer4 as l4
where
    l1.id = l2.id = l3.id = l4.id
```

The principle is demonstrated here with four layers, `layer1` to `layer4`, each having an attribute field called `id` used to join them. Just add more layers using the same pattern in lines 2 and 3.

Comment: i would suggest being  a bit more specific i.e. instead of `select *` use `select l1.*, l2.*, l3.*, l4.*`

Comment: Is there any difference between selecting all and selecting all fields from the layers listed separately?

Comment: Well, at least with `select *` there are undesired copies of the `id` as joined field for each layer, named `id:1`, `id:2` etc.

Answer (score 5):

Additionally, you may try using some PyQGIS for that purpose.

Let's assume there are three layers *'centroids_test'*, *'dresden_buildings_test'*, and *'dresden_buildings_test2'* with corresponding attribute tables, see image below.

[image: input]

Proceed with `Plugins > Python Console > Show Editor` and paste the script below

```py
# your input/main layer
input_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('centroids_test')[0] 
# this is a list with target layers that you would like to join to your input layer
target_layers = ['dresden_buildings_test', 'dresden_buildings_test2']

# mediator fields between input and target layers
input_field, target_field = 'id', 'id'

joinObject = QgsVectorLayerJoinInfo()
joinObject.setJoinFieldName(target_field)
joinObject.setTargetFieldName(input_field)
joinObject.setUsingMemoryCache(True)

for name in target_layers:
    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(name)[0]
    joinObject.setJoinLayerId(layer.id())
    joinObject.setJoinLayer(layer)
    input_layer.addJoin(joinObject)
```

Press `Run script` [image: run script] and get the output that will look like

[image: output]

For more details, please check the [`QgsVectorLayerJoinInfo`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.6/core/QgsVectorLayerJoinInfo.html#module-QgsVectorLayerJoinInfo) class.

---

**References:**

- [Joining layers with PyQGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267732/joining-layers-with-pyqgis-3)
- [Joining table field with shapefile using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133573/joining-table-field-with-shapefile-using-pyqgis)

Comment: Thank you, I actually wrote a script that is very similar to yours following this description:
http://www.qgistutorials.com/de/docs/3/processing_algorithms_pyqgis.html