# Joining Layers with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-joins, qgis-python-console

I need to make a LEFT JOIN (using a Python QGIS script) between two layers:

- a shape (point): s_node
- a csv (table): t_infos

Can you show me how to do that?

The result (the joined layers) has to be in a separated/new/virtual layer.

[image]

My QGIS version: 3.12.3-Bucuresti

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why don't the existing solutions on this site (just look at the "Related" section on the right) work for you?

Comment: I wanted to make a try myself but I don't know how to affect my two layers to two variables in the Python Console. Can you show me please how ? I know that for example the function iface.activeLayer() do something like that but only for the active layer I guess..

Comment: To add a layer as variable you can use ```layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("layer_name")[0]``` if your layer is already in the project. ```layer = iface.addVectorLayer("path_to_your_layer", '', 'ogr')``` if the layer is not in the project. Then you can use one of the script by German Carillo in this post : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133573/joining-table-field-with-shapefile-using-pyqgis?rq=1

Comment: thank you so much @JULESG, it worked 100% !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Joining table field with shapefile using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133573/joining-table-field-with-shapefile-using-pyqgis)